# Redhat subcription-manager register issue

Tags: linux, redhat

Below is the problem of Linux RedHat which I am receiving. on yum command.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum upgrade
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, refresh-packagekit, replace,
          : security, subscription-manager
This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not 
receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
Setting up Upgrade Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                    
| 5.3 kB     00:00
* base: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
* epel: repo.ugm.ac.id
* extras: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
* ius: mirror.team-cymru.org
* updates: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
base                                                                                                                                             
| 3.7 kB     00:00
centos                                                                                                                                           
| 3.7 kB     00:00
 extras                                                                                                                                           
| 3.4 kB     00:00
 ius                                                                                                                                              
| 2.3 kB     00:00
 mongodb                                                                                                                                          
|  951 B     00:00
 mysql-connectors-community                                                                                                                       
| 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql-tools-community                                                                                                                            
 | 2.5 kB     00:00
mysql57-community                                                                                                                                
| 2.5 kB     00:00
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-%24releasever-
x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL 
returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: 
pgdg96. Please verify its path and try again
```

Have already tried most of all the solution mentioned on the net...
 Such as [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/45815) and

Already made an account and also used tried all the subscription manager options commands. But couldn't get around this problem.

I have a server computer where this Redhat is installed.
I got this system from someone else. So I dont have any subscription 16- digit key which is mentioned in Redhat subscription register on Redhat's website.

I have also checked the cd pack which was used to install the redhat on this server computer.

So, I am stuck and dont know how to get around this problem. 
I am unable to install packages or even upgrade as you can see above using

```
# yum install <package-name>
```

This is my OS information

Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Release:        6.5

Codename:       Santiago

Please, if anyone can let me know as to what can be done in this case.

Comment: Disable the repository by `yum-config-manager --disable mysql57-community`. It looks like the site is down.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-%24releasever-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
```

I think your yum version is too old to support the `$releasever` variable.  Try to replace it with `6.5` (your release) in the `.repo` file in the `/etc/yum/repos.d` directory.

This is not really an issue with `subscription-manager` because it concerns a third-party repository (and it's not a programming question, either).